# C++ How to find char in a char array by using find function?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

How to find char in a char array by using find function? If I just for loop the vowel then I could have gotten the answer but I'm asked to use std::find..  Thanks.

```
bool IsVowel (char c) { 

    char vowel[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};            
    bool rtn = std::find(vowel, vowel + 5, c);

    std::cout << " Trace : " << c  << " " << rtn << endl;

    return rtn; 
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
bool IsVowel (char c) { 

    char vowel[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    char* end = vowel + sizeof(vowel) / sizeof(vowel[0]);            
    char* position = std::find(vowel, end, c);

    return (position != end); 
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying and correcting

```
inline bool IsVowel(char c) {
    return std::string("aeiou").find(c) != std::string::npos;
}
```

See a demo http://ideone.com/NnimDH.

Comment: This is very late, but std::string allocates data on the heap, which is slower than allocating on the stack.

Answer (score 3):

`std::find(first, last, value)` returns an iterator to the first element which matches `value` in range [first, last). If there's no match, it returns `last`.

In particular, std::find does not return a boolean. To get the boolean you're looking for, you need to compare the return value (without converting it to a boolean first!) of std::find to `last` (i.e. if they are equal, no match was found).

Comment: Do I have to use char::iterator? I think there is no such things as char:iterator, right? What kind of iterator should I use? And how to check whether it's end or not? Normally, if it's a string, we can do like s.end() == it but array doens't have .end().

Comment: char* (pointer to char) is an iterator in this context. Your `end` in your example is `vowel+5`. It would, of course, be somewhat easier (or less complex) to use std::vector or std::string.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
size_t find_first_of ( char c, size_t pos = 0 ) const;
```

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/

Comment: The question was about an an array of characters not an std::string

Answer (score -2):

Looking for the sequence of a character in an array - why drag bool into it. Give a simple straightforward answer if you can.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    using namespace std;
    //Position
    int posc(char suit[], char fc, int sz)
        {
            int i = 0;
            do
            {
                if (toupper(fc) == suit[i]) return i;
                else
                i = i + 1;
            } 
            while (i < sz);
            cout << "\n Character " << fc << " not available in list";
            return 99;
        }
    int main()
    {
        char suit[] = { 'S', 'D', 'C', 'H' };
        char fc;
        int res;
        int sz = size(suit);
        cout << "\n Enter a character: ";
        cin >> fc;
        res = posc(suit, fc, sz);
        cout << "\n Sequence no: " << res;
        return 0;
    }
```

The main & cout frills are added just to show a working solution

Comment: Could you please provide more details about your solution?

Comment: See above - all that it spits out is a sequence number.

Comment: The original question asked about how to use ```std::find``` for this. I don't see you using this function.